Stickfight the Game Ragdoll Physics
I'm trying to make an active ragdoll in Unity 2D. The problem is that when you see mine as compared to Stickfight the Game or Off the Sticks, mine is very stiff and "janky". I just don't see how to get the softer, more fluid motion found in other games. Even looking here:
Clip of Game - Reddit, it looks and feels very different. I just don't see what I'm missing.
Movement script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StickmanController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D torsoRb;
    public Rigidbody2D[] limbs;
    public float uprightTorque = 200f;    // Keeps the torso facing up
    public float movementForce = 10f;     // Controls forward movement
    public float limbSwingForce = 50f;    // Floppy limb force
    public float correctionThreshold = 45f; // Max angle before correction kicks in

    private bool movingRight = false;
    private bool movingLeft = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        // Capture input for movement
        movingRight = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D);
        movingLeft = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Apply upright balance with controlled limits
        KeepTorsoUpright();

        // Apply movement force if input is detected
        if (movingRight)
        {
            PropelCharacter(Vector2.right);
        }
        else if (movingLeft)
        {
            PropelCharacter(Vector2.left);
        }

        // Make limbs swing randomly for floppy movement
        SwingLimbs();
    }

    private void KeepTorsoUpright()
    {
        // Only apply balance correction within an acceptable angle range
        float currentAngle = torsoRb.rotation;
        if (currentAngle > correctionThreshold || currentAngle < -correctionThreshold)
        {
            float targetAngle = 0f; // Target upright orientation
            float angleDifference = Mathf.DeltaAngle(currentAngle, targetAngle);
            
            // Apply upright torque only to correct within range
            float torque = -angleDifference * uprightTorque;
            torsoRb.AddTorque(torque * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void PropelCharacter(Vector2 direction)
    {
        torsoRb.AddForce(direction * movementForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode2D.Force);
    }

    private void SwingLimbs()
    {
        foreach (Rigidbody2D limb in limbs)
        {
            Vector2 randomDirection = new Vector2(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), Random.Range(-1f, 1f)).normalized;
            limb.AddForce(randomDirection * limbSwingForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
    }
}

```


Is the linked clip from your game? I've played Stick Fight and this doesn't look any more "janky" than it. Can you be more specific about the problem you're having?

@ChristopherWells No, that's what I want it to look like. That's just an example. Mine is very stiff, slides around, etc.

Ok. Can we have an example of what your game looks like, or perhaps some code if it's not too long? It's hard to answer "why does my game look bad" when we don't know what your game looks like.

@ChristopherWells Added my code for movement.

It's not clear to me how your movement differs from what you've shown. "Softer/more fluid" is a pretty subjective assessment: a concrete example video or gif showing your current movement would better help a reader understand the problem you need help fixing.

If it generally works as you want, but it's "jerky", then you need "more frames" if you want to smooth things out.
